# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null message = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement.firstChild.data;

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am following the newboston ajax tutorial but have faced  error.
i have given the snapshot of the error.I am using wamp server and have run it on chrome browser.

Can anyone help me?

[image: Error]

[image: Rendered HTML]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
             <head>
                    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                    <meta content="utf=8" http-equiv="encoding">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="food.js"></script>
            </head>
                <body onload="process()">
                    <h2>....Food Shop...</h2>
                    <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="enter the food u want" value="banana">
                    <div id="underinput" />
                </body>
            </html>
```

food.js

```
var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){

    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObjects){
        try{
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }
        catch(e)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try{
                xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e)
        {
                xmlHttp=false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp)
    {
    alert("cant create the object");
    }
    else{
         return xmlHttp;
    }
}


function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0){
        food=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food=" + food,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);


    }else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);


    }
}
function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if(xmlHttp.status == 200){


             message = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underinput").innerHTML= '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()',1000);   
        }else{
            alert('something wrong...');
        }
    }
}
```

foodstore.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    int_set('display_errors',true)
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF=8" standalone="yes" ?>';
    echo '<response>';
        $food = $_GET['food'];
        $foodArray= array('banana','apple','mango');
        if(in_array($food,$foodArray)){
            echo 'we do have'.$food;
        }
        else if($food ==''){
            echo 'enter the food';
        }
        else{
            echo 'sorry we do not have'.$food;
            }
    echo '</response>';
?>
```

Comment: It's telling you `xmlHttp.responseXML` is null, so you should log that, and see what the server is really returning

Comment: can you please tell me how to log

Comment: `console.log( xmlHttp.responseXML )` and `console.log( typeof xmlHttp.responseXML )`

Comment: That ajax function is now very outdated - if you are just learning all about ajax you ought perhaps to look instead at the `fetch` api ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API )

Comment: not working still same problem

Comment: The XML that you are generating - does it look valid if you were to load `foodstore.php?food=apple` directly in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The fault, I believe, lies in the PHP code that generates the XML data. When I tried using that code I got an error when I attempted to parse the xml using javascript. The error I got was:

> This page contains the following errors:error on line 1 at column 34:
>   String not closed expecting " or ' Below is a rendering of the page up
>   to the first error.

As you are using PHP to generate the xml why not use the correct methods that are part of core PHP - namely `DOMDocument`?

The following is a modified version of your code and should return the response you are working towards.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['food'] ) ){

        /* Filter the input data */
        $food = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'food', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        /* an array of foodstuffs */
        $foods = array('banana','apple','mango','orange','plum','peach','cherry','kiwi','grape','lemon');

        /* Construct the response message based upon existance of food */
        $message = empty( $food ) ? 'enter the food' : ( in_array( $food, $foods ) ? 'We do have '.$food : 'Sorry, we do not have '.$food );


        /* using DOMDocument to output a correctly formed XML document */
        $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $dom->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'response', $message ) );
        $xml = $dom->saveXML();
        $dom=null;


        /* send the response */
        header('Content-Type: application/xml');
        exit( $xml );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax and XML</title>
        <script>
            /* lightweight utility function for making ajax requests */
            function ajax(url,method,params,callback){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.onerror=function(e){
                    console.log(e)
                };
                var payload=[];
                for( var n in params )payload.push( n + '=' + params[ n ] );
                var p;

                switch( method.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=payload.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': url+='?'+payload.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }
                xhr.open( method.toUpperCase(), url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }

            /* utility function to get a parser to process XML data */
            function get_parser(str_xml) {
                try {
                    if( window.XMLSerializer && typeof( DOMParser )!='undefined' ) {
                        var parser = new DOMParser();
                        return parser.parseFromString(str_xml, 'application/xml');

                    } else if( typeof( ActiveXObject ) != 'undefined' ) {
                        var parser = CreateMSXMLDocumentObject();
                            parser.async='false';
                            parser.load( str_xml );
                        return parser;

                    } else {
                        var url = 'data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent( str_xml );
                        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            request.open( 'GET', url, false );
                            request.send( null );
                        return request.responseXML;

                    }
                } catch( err ) {
                    console.warn( err );
                }
            }

            function process(){
                /*
                    Change to suit your environment ~ for this demo I use same page ( location.href )
                */
                var food = document.querySelector('input[name="food"]').value;
                if( food && food!='' ){
                    //ajax.call( this, 'foodstore.php', 'get', { food:food }, handleServerResponse );

                    ajax.call( this, location.href, 'get', { food:food }, handleServerResponse );
                }
            }

            /* callback function to process xml response data */
            function handleServerResponse(response){
                if( response ){

                    /* parse xml response */
                    var xml=get_parser( response );

                    /* get the node which is of interest - only one in this case */
                    var message = xml.documentElement.textContent;

                    /* output message to browser */
                    document.getElementById("underinput").innerHTML= '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
                }
            }


            function bindEvents(e){
                document.getElementById('bttn').onclick=process;
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,{ passive:true, capture:false } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='geronimo'>
            <label for='food'>Enter Food<input type='text' name='food' placeholder='eg: apple' size=60 /></label>
            <input type='button' id='bttn' value='Check' />
            <div id='underinput'></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```